# best algorithm to find words in a paragraph?

Tags: string, algorithm

given a paragraph of text and a list of strings return a list of strings that are contained in the paragraph.
notice that in the list of string each string can contain multiple words.
for example
input text is "i love java program" and the string list is{"java","java program","java and c program"} should return {"java program"}
What is the best algorithm and data structure to use in term of time complexity

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried till now ?

Comment: why it will not return "java" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't specify that the returned list should be a (presumably maximum) subset of the given list. Therefore, the best algorithm is the trivial O(1) solution: `return [string(paragraph[0])]`.

Comment: The description also doesn't specify that the paragraph is nonempty, so `parargraph[0]` might be undefined.